# Как удалить объект из ArrayList?

Tags: java

Всем привет. Такой вопрос, есть коллекция:

```
private List<ToDoDocument> listDocument = new ArrayList<ToDoDocument>();
```

Содержит объект "записки".

Добавляю туда заметки, а потом хочу удалить одну из них:

```
listDocument.remove(todo);
```

Но не удаляет, почему?

Comment: эм, вы пытаетесь удалить из списка *класс*?

Comment: @Etki  если бы он удалял из листа класс, это было бы так    `listDocument.remove(ToDoDocument);`, но этот бред невозможен, к счастью.

Comment: @argamidon, все в ревизиях

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для поиска элемента, который надо удалить из `ArrayList`'а, используется метод `equals`. Весьма вероятно, что вы его либо неправильно переопределили, либо его наоборот, вам его нужно переопределить (поскольку базовая имплементация сравнивает ссылки).

А возможно вы пытаетесь удалить элемент, которого в списке вовсе нет.

Покажите полный код, включая ToDoDocument.

Comment: эх, не успел. да, тут скорее всего именно в этом дело

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку, теперь понятно, через что он удаляет. Надо переопределить метод equals.

Comment: Простите, а что вы подразумеваете, когда говорите что базовая имплементация `equals` работает медленно? По вашему, сранение двух ссылок - это медленная операция?

Comment: метод equals НЕ перегружается. Он переопределяется. Не надо  путать людей и манипулировать терминами. [на почитай][1]


  [1]: http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/java-questions/method-overriding-vs-overloading/

Comment: просто не работает базовая equals. Динамически добавляю в коллекцию но не удаляется. А вот если переопределить equals И там сравнивать name

Comment: если не работает базовая функция, значит у вас объекты разные при сравнении, а точнее их хэш. Следовательно вы сравнивайте разные объекты, а не идентичные. И нечего лезть тут да куда не надо, оставьте в покое equals и проверяйте свой заголовок в итеративном цикле.

Comment: Виноват, переработал :). `equals()` действительно использует сравнение ссылок. А про перегрузить/переопределить оговорился.

Исправил ответ, спасибо за замечания.